# Iterative Meets of Posets

Tags: order-theory

Let $(P,\preceq)$ be a poset, where for each element $x \in P$ there finite elements $y \preceq x, y \in P$. Typically, the meet of a set of elements is supposed to be unique, however, I'm going to change that slightly. For a finite set of elements $S$, let $L(S)$ be the lower-bound set of $S$, thus $L(S) := \{x \in P | x \preceq y \forall y \in S\}$. Now, let $Meet(S,0)$ be the maximal of $L(S)$, namely, $Meet(S,0) := \{x \in L(S) | \nexists y \in L(S)\setminus x, x \preceq y \}$.

Then, for each positive integer $i$, $Meet(S,i) := Meet(Meet(S,i-1),0)$. If $Meet(S,i)$ is one element, $z$, then $Meet(S,i+k) = z$ for all positive $k$ as well. Is there a name for this kind of iterative meet? Are there important posets whose have the property that $Meet(S,i-1)$ can have multiple elements but $Meet(S,i)$ is always a single element, for $i > 0$, $|S|=2$?

Comment: Meet(S,1) = Meet(Meet(S,1),1) does not define Meet(S,1).

Comment: In general, in a poset, you can’t just take meets or joins or arbitrary sets of elements; for starters, meets and joins are only defined for **lattices**, not arbitrary posets; and second, they are only defined for pairs of elements (and inductively for finite subsets of elements).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin updated to make things finite/countable to better reflect what I meant

Comment: Your $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$ is the set of maximal elements in the set of lower bounds for $S$. For arbitrary posets, it is possible for this set to be empty even if the set of lower bounds is not; your condition of finiteness excludes that, but now it is easy to construct posets in which the set shrinks by any amount you care to specify ahead of time (ncluding starting at $n$ and going to empty in one step). However, note that this process will *not* agree with what you may think of as a “meet” (cont)

Comment: (cont) For instance, if $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$ has more than one element, then none of those elements are lower bounds for the set itself, so $\mathrm{Meet}(S,1)$ will, if it contains any elements, contain only elements strictly smaller than elements in $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$. And so at each step you are going “further away” from your original $S$, with more and more things in between the elements you have and the elements of your original set $S$.

Comment: I think (I’ll try to work it out later) that if at any stage $\mathrm{Meet}(S,i)$ has more than one element, then all those elements are removed in the next iterative set; and if it has a single element, then the process just repeats the set itself. So you will either end up with the empty set or a unique element.

Comment: I don’t see how you’d end up with an empty set

Comment: You end up with the empty set for instance if you have the poset $\{a,b,c,d\}$, with $a\leq c,d$, $b\leq c,d$, and $S=\{c,d\}$. After one iteration, you get $\{a,b\}$. But this set has no lower bounds, so the next step is empty.

Comment: P.S. Your definition of $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$ is **not** “the upper bounds of $L(S)$. The upper bounds of $L(S)$ would be $\{x\in P\mid \forall y\in L(S) (y\leq x)\}$. Your definition is that it is the set of maximal elements in $L(S)$.

Comment: In that case, $Meet(\{a,b\},0)$ is simply $\{a,b\}$. I do not wish for the upper bound, but simply the elements of $L(S)$ which are not less than another element in $L(S)$, which I believe I properly defined above

Comment: No, $\mathrm{Meet}(\{a,b\},0)$ is not $\{a,b\}$, because neither $a$ nor $b$ are lower bounds for $\{a,b\}$. In order to be a lower bound, you must be less than or equal to all elements of $\{a,b\}$, and since $a$ and $b$ are incomparable, **neither** of them is a lower bound for $\{a,b\}$. So $L(\{a,b\})$ is empty, and thus $\mathrm{Meet}(\{a,b\},0)$ is empty as well. Your written definition captures what you say in the comment, but not what you say before its definition in your post, which say "the upper bounds of $L(S)$".

Comment: Don't call the  "largest", call them what they are called: **maximal** elements.

Comment: alright thanks, sorry I've never had formal learning in order theory.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset. If $S\subseteq P$, then $x\in P$ is a *lower bound for $S$* if and only if $x\leq s$ for all $s\in S$.  An element $x\in S$ is *maximal in $S$* if for all $y\in S$, $x\leq y\implies x=y$; and dually, $x\in S$ is *minimal in $S$* if for all $z\in S$, $z\leq x\implies z=x$. An element $t\in S$ is a *minimum for $S$* if $t\leq s$ for all $s\in S$, and a *maximum for $S$ if $s\leq t$ for all $s\in S$. Finally, an element $x\in P$ is the *infimum* of $S$ if $x\leq s$ for all $s\in S$, and if $y\leq s$ for all $s\in S$, then $y\leq x$. Dually the *supremum of $S$* is an element $x\in P$ such that $s\leq x$ for all $s\in S$, and if $s\leq y$ for all $s\in S$, then $x\leq y$.

So, your $L(S)$ is the set of lower bounds of $S$, and $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$ is the set of maximal elements in $L(S)$. Then you look at the lower bounds of this set, and take the maximal elements of *that*, etc.

We are assuming that your $P$, even if not finite, has the property that for every nonempty subset $S$, $L(S)$ is finite (since you are asking that each *element* have a finite set of lower bounds, and $L(S) = \cap L(\{s\})$ with the intersection running over all $s\in S$). That ensures that every element in $L(S)$ is less than or equal to a maximal element, and that $L(S)$ either has a maximum, or else has two or more maximal elements.

If $L(S)$ has two or more maximal elements, then $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$ is an **antichain**: a set in which no two elements are comparable. To see this, note that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct maximal elements of $L(S)$, then they must be incomparable: for if $x\leq y$ then $x=y$ (since $x$ is maximal), and likewise if $y\leq x$ then $y=x$ because $y$ is maximal.

Now, here's the thing: if $S$ is a set, $x,y\in S$, and $x$ and $y$ are incomparable, then **neither** $x$ nor $y$ are in $L(S)$: for if $z\in L(S)$, then $z\leq x$ and $z\leq y$; and since $x\nleq y$ then $x\notin L(S)$, and similary $y\nleq x\implies y\notin L(S)$.

That means that if $\mathrm{Meet}(S,k)$ has more than one element, then **none** of them can be in $\mathrm{Meet}(S,k+1)$: for none of them are in $L(\mathrm{Meet}(S,k))$, and hence none of them are maximal in $L(\mathrm{Meet}(S,k))$.

Now, after your first step, you have a subset of $L(S)$. If this subset has more than one element, then in your next step you will get a subset of $L(S)-\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)$. If this set has more than one element, then your next step will yield a subset of $L(S) - (\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)\cup\mathrm{Meet}(S,1))$; etc.

Thus, you start with a finite $L(S)$. And at each step you get either (i) the empty set; or (ii) a singleton; or (iii) you get more than one element, and in the next step you will get a subset of an ever-shrinking finite set. That means that you will eventually get a single element, or you will get the empty set.

Yes, the empty set is possible: if $P=\{a,b,c,d\}$, and the only relations in addition to the reflexive one are $a\leq c$, $a\leq d$, $b\leq c$, and $b\leq d$, and we let $S=\{c,d\}$ then the set of lower bounds is $\{a,b\}$, both of which are maximal in $L(S)$. So $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0)=L(S) = \{a,b\}$. But now, **neither** $a$ nor $b$ are in $L(\{a,b\})$ (and neither are $c$ and $d$, of course), and in fact $L(\{a,b\})$ is empty, and so $\mathrm{Meet}(S,1)=\varnothing$.

On the other hand, if you get $\mathrm{Meet}(S,k)$ a singleton, then $\mathrm{Meet}(S,k+1)=\mathrm{Meet}(S,k)$, for the element itself is a lower bound and is, by construction, the maximum of the set of lower bounds.

So the only two possible eventual outcomes are: you will reach the empty set, or you will reach a singleton.

However, a singleton is not necessarily an object you may want to call the meet of $S$. For instance, consider the following poset: $P=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\}$.
Now, I'll give you the least order relations (no element between the two I list, extend transitively, add the reflexivity):

- $c\lt a$, $c\lt b$;
- $d\lt a$, $d\lt b$;
- $e\lt a$, $e\lt b$;
- $f\lt c$, $f\lt d$, $f\lt e$;
- $g\lt d$; $g\lt e$;
- $h\lt c$; $h\lt g$
- $i\lt h$; $i\lt f$.

All elements except $a$ and $b$ are less than or equal to each of $a$ and $b$. I can't draw a diagram here (I would normally use `xymatrix` which I believe is not MathJax supported), but you should try drawing an order diagram for this to see how it looks. I'm not sure what *I* would call "the meet of $\{a,b\}$", but your process yields the minimum of $P$, even though there are lots of other elements that are less than or equal to all of $a$ and $b$.

Indeed, take $S=\{a,b\}$. then $L(S) = P\setminus\{a,b\}$, and the maximal elements of $L(S)$ are $c$, $d$, and $e$. So $\mathrm{Meet}(S,0) = \{c,d,e\}$.

Now, the lower bounds of $\{c,d,e\}$ $f$, $h$, and $i$; $g$ is not, becase $g\not\lt c$. The maximal elements among them are $f$ and $h$, so $\mathrm{Meet}(S,1) = \{f,h\}$.

And now $L(\{f,h\})= \{i\}$, so the process terminates.

If you remove the relation $i\lt f$, then $L(\{f,h\})$ is empty, and you get the empty set, even though you still have that $i$ is less than or equal to $a$ and $b$ (and $c$, $d$, $e$, $g$, and $h$; everything except for $f$, in fact).

So I don't think thar your process captures what you want it to capture; you can define posets in which the process just keeps going "further down away from $S$" at every step, and ends in either the empty set or a singleton, as you wish.

Note that if $L(S)$ has a minimum, then the process will not end with the empty set, but it could not end until you get to the minimum... or it could end arbitrarily "above" the minimum (if you have a "choke point" between the minimum and the set $S$, for example).

So I suspect that this idea does not capture what you want it to capture, and so I would be surprised if it has a formal name.

---

Now, the meet of two elements is usually defined to be their greatest lower bound. A poset in which any two elements have a meet is called a *lower semilattice*. In a lower semilattice, any nonempty *finite* subset has a greatest lower bound; if in addition every infinite subset also has a greatest lower bound, we say that the poset is a **complete* lower semilattice. The dual concept for least upper bounds is the join, and you get upper semilattices and complete upper semilattices. If you have both least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds, and they satisfiy the absorption properties, then you get a lattice (and a *complete lattice* if you also get lubs and glbs for infinite subsets). There is a very rich theory of lattices, of course.

Comment: I’m surprised that this doesn’t have a name! I thought it was quite natural when thinking about counting unlabeled rooted subtrees, because if there were a fixed finite number of meets that found a common sub tree of several branches, you could potentially get a nice algorithm. (however I don’t think that subtrees have that property, I nonetheless was just intrigued by the idea of iterative meets)

Comment: @ZacharyHunter: I'm not an ordered theorist, so I don't know if it has a name. But I would certainly not call the result a **meet**; it just doesn't have the properties that order theorists think of when you call something a meet.